# constraints cause an ambiguousLayout

Tags: objective-c, macos, constraints

I have a `NSWindow` instance which have a `setupUi` method.

```
-(void) setupUi {
    NSView* subView = [[NSView alloc] initWithFrame:NSZeroRect];
    subView.wantsLayer = YES;
    subView.layer.backgroundColor = [[NSColor greenColor] CGColor];
    [self.contentView addSubview:subView];
    [self.contentView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [self.contentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.contentView
                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                 toItem:subView
                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                             multiplier:1
                               constant:0]];
    [self.contentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.contentView
                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                 toItem:subView
                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                             multiplier:1
                               constant:0]];
    [self.contentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.contentView
                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                 toItem:subView
                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                             multiplier:1
                               constant:0]];
    [self.contentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.contentView
                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                 toItem:subView
                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                             multiplier:1
                               constant:0]];

}
```

When I call `[self.contentView hasAmbiguousLayout]`, it returns YES. Why it happened? This code snippet seems to be the same as something Xib has created for us while using pin panel.

And the subView with green color doesn't appear in the window.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The property of **translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints** of **NSWindow**'s contentView is default YES. I can't guess what will happen with my knowledge of **Frame**, **AutoResizingMask**, **AutoLayout** if i set it to NO because the behavior i have tried makes me terribly confused.

In a word, leave the top contentView's translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints as YES, but all of other subviews as NO if i want to only use **AutoLayout**.

When you create a view, it is constructed with autoResizingMask of 0 and translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints of YES. If translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints is YES, it will use Frame, autoResizingMask and even constraints(AutoLayout) to position a view.

Consider a situation below.

```
NSView* subView = [[NSView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(100, 100, 200, 200)];
subView.wantsLayer = YES;
subView.layer.backgroundColor = [[NSColor greenColor] CGColor];
[subView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:YES];
[self.contentView addSubview:subView];

[subView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:subView
                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                             toItem:nil
                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                         multiplier:1
                           constant:50]];
[subView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:subView
                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                             toItem:nil
                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                         multiplier:1
                           constant:50]];
```

The translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints of subView is YES. Then it will use the Point(100, 100) to position it. It will use Size(200, 200) to size it. It will create NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint to make it unresizable because the default autoResizingMask is 0 which means a view can't change its width and height. It will also create NSLayoutConstraint with autoLayout because you have called "addConstraint". And it will also break the NSLayoutConstraint because your NSLayoutConstraint and NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint are conflicted. Terribly terrible.

But if you call **[subView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO]**, it will not use the Point, the Size, the NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint, it will only use NSLayoutConstraint with autoLayout. Because you only size it, not position it. So it's an ambiguous layout. Terribly terrible.

The code below is True.

```
NSView* subView = [[NSView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(100, 100, 200, 200)];
subView.wantsLayer = YES;
subView.layer.backgroundColor = [[NSColor greenColor] CGColor];
[subView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[self.contentView addSubview:subView];

[subView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:subView
                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                             toItem:nil
                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                         multiplier:1
                           constant:50]];
[subView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:subView
                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                             toItem:nil
                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                         multiplier:1
                           constant:50]];
[self.conteView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:subView
                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                             toItem:self.contentView
                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                         multiplier:1
                           constant:0]];
[self.conteView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:subView
                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                             toItem:self.contentView
                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                         multiplier:1
                           constant:0]];
```

I think cocoa's layout is such a terrible thing, many reasons.

In Qt, QHBoxLayout can do it very easily. Do not tell me there is NSStackView in cocoa, i feel very tired to debug it when it goes wrong without rhyme or reason.

But i have to work with cocoa.

Is there someone who can tell me why i can't set contentView's translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to NO?

Thanks in advance.